# Change mapped list when input changed

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and I want to generate a component that maps a list from an array.  I then want to be able to update this array and the list will also update.

Here is some example code:

```js
function ListItem(props) {
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function NumberList(props) {
  let numbers = props.numbers;

  function changeNumbers() {
    numbers = [3, 2, 1];
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input type="text" onChange={changeNumbers} />
      <ul>
        {numbers.map((number) => (
          <ListItem key={number.toString()} value={number} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList numbers={numbers} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Embed doesn't seem to want to run so here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/GuerrillaCoder/pen/KKzyLqR

I'm lacking the terminology here but how do I bind the list output to the array so when I edit the array the list will then update with the new values.

This example is contrived but what I am hoping to build is a text input that will filter results in a list.

Comment: I've updated your code snippet to use explicit fragment components (<React.Fragment>) so that it will run within the code snippet

Comment: Another way to get a runnable snippet is to manually add the current version of [Babel Standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone) - the one Stack Overflow uses is too old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `useState` and use the `numbers` prop as the initial value. On change, call the state dispatch function (`setNumbers`) to update the component's state:

```js
function ListItem(props) {
  return <li>{props.value}</li>;
}

function NumberList(props) {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = React.useState(props.numbers);
  function changeNumbers() {
    setNumbers([3, 2, 1]);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input type="text" onChange={changeNumbers} />
      <ul>
        {numbers.map((number) => (
          <ListItem key={number.toString()} value={number} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList numbers={numbers} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

(The second item returned by `useState` is a function which corresponds to `setState` outside a functional component)